# How to expand the width of a div to get beyond its parent width?

Tags: css

This is a snippet of the code

```
<div id="container">
   <article>
      <p>contents</p>
      <img ... />
      <footer>meta data</footer>
   </article
</div>

#container{
  width:960px;
          }
article{
  width:640px; 
      }
footer, img{
    width:960px; /*well I may want it 640px but float right all the way back to the edge of #container*/
      }
```

The footer and image do not take that width; I tried the `position:absolute` and it works, but they go to the top, even when I add `position: relative` to the container.

Normally I would close the article tag, add the image, and then start with the article. This is not an ideal solution.

Comment: First, make sure you do not have any of the errors in your actual code that you have in this question.  Potion: absolute will do nothing.  Second, ensure you are using Strict doc type.  Third, please state the problem a little clearer and what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: If you're trying to limit the width of the "contents", why not set the width of the `p` element instead of `article`? And then you don't have to worry about going outside `article`'s boundaries. And floating the `img` will then push it all the way to `#container`'s right boundary.

Comment: I am really sorry for my errors in the question. I did read it 3 times before posting - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that they need to be `block` or `inline-block` to accept a width. Floats could cause weird wrapping. You could try `overflow: visible` to see if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track with positioning.  You want to set the container to relative and then the inner element set to absolute, pinned to the top right corner:

```
#container{ width:960px; position: relative; }
img, footer{ width:960px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;}
```

An absolute positioned element is relative to its first positioned ancestor, so the inner element is positioned based on #container.

Comment: This makes the footer and image go up I need the image to stay where it is just get bigger

Comment: if you're planning on keeping the width static you can do `footer, img{ width:960px; position: relative; right: -320px; left: 0px;`

Comment: Take the img part out, and use bottom for the footer instead of top

Comment: it is an article so I would never know the position of the image, I  did try that before writing the question. though I got what I needed thanks